# Adobe Creative Cloud TCP Connections TCPview

Tags: windows, process, svchost

I am going through my windows ten pc and checking all the connections to make sure everything is in order. I used the netstat -b command and it brought back a lot more than I was expecting so I started to investigate. I downloaded tcp view and there are a ton of connections. There are Adobe Desktop Service Connections that are on port 0 and the remote address is listed as 0.0.0.0, is this normal? There are also like 20 winstore.exe connections and they all have different addresses. What is the best way to check that these connections are legitimate and not someone migrating something malicious onto an existing process with something like metasploit? Also svchost has a ton. I've heard reports of microsoft signing malware with their sha signature so I would like to find a concrete way to determine which of these processes are legitimate.

I tried looking for sha signatures but as previously mentioned there are reports of malware being signed as legitimate by microsoft. I'm looking for the best way to tell if they are legitimate. Additionally, wouldn't a malicious process that has been migrated onto a legitimate one share the sha signature?